# How to get 7 highest value from the array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I want to get 7 highes values from my array, but it should be sorted properly

I have this code:

```
<?php    
$nilai = array(72,65,73,78,75,74,90,81,87,65,55,69,72,78,79,91,100,40,67,77,86);
$jumlah = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($nilai)-1; $i++)
{
    $jumlah += $nilai[$i];
}
$rata = $jumlah/count($nilai);
$max = $nilai[0];
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($nilai)-1; $i++)
{
    if ($nilai[$i] > $max)
    {
        $max = $nilai[$i];
    }
    rsort($nilai);
    $top7 = array_reverse(array_slice($nilai, 0, 7));
}
echo "Rata-Rata : ".$rata;
echo "<br>";
echo "Tertinggi : ".$top7;
?>
```

Output :

Tertinggi :  100,91,90,87,86,81,79

Comment: What is exactly the problem with your code? It seems that you do get the top 7 values already.

Comment: define "properly". You can either have it in reverse order, or not. Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5b45e390ee53e7564b6d49937610dc915396bcbd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code almost get the right output, except you cannot echo an array, you need to use `print_r()` or some other method to convert the array to a string.

But to make the code more compact, the following uses just the minimum (I can think of anyway) code...

```
$nilai = array(72,65,73,78,75,74,90,81,87,65,55,69,72,78,79,91,100,40,67,77,86);

// Average
$jumlah = array_sum($nilai);
$rata = $jumlah / count ( $nilai );
echo "Rata-Rata : ".$rata;
echo "<br>";

// Top 7
rsort($nilai);
$top7 = array_slice($nilai, 0, 7 );

echo "Tertinggi : ";
print_r($top7);
```